# How can I set column in data frames in list as factor?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of 10 dataframes, on which I want to apply several functions. I am quite new to R. I searched on the internet but can't find the solution.

The dataframes all have the same variables. I want to set the data type of one variable as a factor (which is now integer), having two levels: wetland and no wetland (1 or 0) in every dataframe. This variable is in the third column.

I tried something like this but I can't find the right code:

```
factorcol = "WETLAND"
datalist[, factorcol] <- lapply(datalist[,factor_cols], factor)
datalist[, factorcol] <- lapply (levels (datalist[,factorcol]))<-c("no wetl","wetl")
```

Or should I use `as.factor` which I would use if I treated a dataframe seperately? And how I apply it to third column of all dataframes in the list?

Comment: Try something like `datalist <- lapply(datalist, function(i){i$WETLAND <- as.factor(i$WETLAND, ...); i})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to apply this to only one column, you don't need `lapply` to iterate over columns. Use `lapply` to iterate over dataframes and change the 3rd column to factor specifying `labels` and `levels`.

```
datalist <- lapply(datalist, function(x) {
              x[[3]] <- factor(x[[3]], levels = c(0, 1), 
                               labels = c("no wetl","wetl"))
              x
             })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the column you want to convert to factor, you can simply do,

```
datalist <- lapply(datalist, function(i){i$WETLAND <- as.factor(i$WETLAND, ...); i})
```